# Output raw value difference from one period to the next using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a dataset, df, where I have a new value for each day. I would like to output the percent difference of these values from row to row as well as the raw value difference:

```
        Date             Value

        10/01/2020      1
        10/02/2020      2
        10/03/2020      5
        10/04/2020      8
```

Desired output:

```
        Date            Value   PercentDifference    ValueDifference

        10/01/2020      1       
        10/02/2020      2       100                   2
        10/03/2020      5       150                   3
        10/04/2020      8       60                    3
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')   

 df = (df.merge(df.assign(Date=df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta('1D')),
      on='Date')
 .assign(Value = lambda x: x['Value_y']-x['Value_x'])
 [['Date','Value']]
  )  


 df['PercentDifference'] = [f'{x:.2%}' for x in (df['Value'].div(df['Value'].shift(1)) - 
 1).fillna(0)]
```

A member has helped me with the code above, I am also trying to incorporate the value difference as shown in my desired output.

**Note** - Is there a way to incorporate a 'period' - say, checking the percent difference and value difference over a 7 day period and 30 day period and so on?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) and [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff)

```
df['PercentageDiff'] = df['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)
df['ValueDiff'] = df['Value'].diff()

         Date  Value  PercentageDiff  ValueDiff
0  10/01/2020      1             NaN        NaN
1  10/02/2020      2           100.0        1.0
2  10/03/2020      5           150.0        3.0
3  10/04/2020      8            60.0        3.0
```

Or you use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df.assign(
    percentageDiff=df["Value"].pct_change().mul(100), 
    ValueDiff=df["Value"].diff()
)
```

Comment: Hi  @Ch3steR, thank you, I will try this- I am wondering, how would I incorporate this code if I wish to see the difference and percent change over 7 days or 30 days. I am researching the documentation and see you can periods?

Comment: @Lynnette `groupby` over period using `pd.Grouper`, then use `sum` to get total value in each period. Now, apply `pct_change` and `diff`

Comment: Couldn't I also use: DataFrame.diff(periods=1, axis=0) , and put in the desired periods?

Comment: @Lynnette `Series.diff`'s `period` parameter does something different from what you are thinking basically what it does is for example period is 2 it subtracts a row with a row above by 2 indices. Take a look at [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: Based on your input and my research, I would apply something like this to find a week by week difference: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='7D', origin='start')).sum() ? I am unsure of the origin though. Perhaps this would be the starting date? Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='7D')).sum()` should do it. @Lynnette

Comment: Thank you for your input

Comment: @Lynnette Glad to have helped. GL ;)